# Lagom does not work with Postgresql as persistence database

Tags: postgresql, scala, jndi, lagom

I am trying to use Postgresql as the database for persistence in my lagom application.

Below is the configuration I did in my application.conf

```
db.default {
  driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"
  url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres"
}

jdbc-defaults.slick.profile = "slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile$"
```

I also mixed the application class with `JdbcPersistenceComponents` and `HikariCPComponents` as stated in the logam documentation. However, when I run the flow which involves persistent entities, I get following error

```
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: DefaultDB not found
    at tyrex.naming.MemoryContext.internalLookup(Unknown Source)
    at tyrex.naming.MemoryContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at akka.persistence.jdbc.util.SlickDatabase$.$anonfun$database$3(SlickDatabase.scala:68)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:242)
    at akka.persistence.jdbc.util.SlickDatabase$.$anonfun$database$2(SlickDatabase.scala:68)
    at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:477)
    at akka.persistence.jdbc.util.SlickDatabase$.database(SlickDatabase.scala:67)
    at akka.persistence.jdbc.util.SlickDatabase$.initializeEagerly(SlickDatabase.scala:79)
    at akka.persistence.jdbc.util.DefaultSlickDatabaseProvider.database(SlickExtension.scala:84)
    at akka.persistence.jdbc.util.SlickExtensionImpl.database(SlickExtension.scala:43)
    at akka.persistence.jdbc.journal.JdbcAsyncWriteJournal.<init>(JdbcAsyncWriteJournal.scala:61)
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```

Do I miss any configuartion/setup ?

Thank you for help in advance.

Comment: Have you injected PersistentEntityRegistry into your service implementation? This may fix your problem (cf. https://gitter.im/lagom/lagom?at=5df79493f1cc6c27ea5c9dff)

Answer (score 0):

To use a relational database add the following in your project’s build:

```
libraryDependencies += lagomScaladslPersistenceJdbc
```